# Conectar con flechas los puntos de datos de una variable, ordenados según otra variable

Tags: r

Tengo un conjunto de datos similar a este [ejemplo mínimo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fo7g41kw0epyvvh/arrows.csv?dl=0).

Estoy graficando Quality vs. Speed usando ggplot.

```
ggplot(df_2,aes(x = Speed, y = Quality, k=GAME.ID) +
  geom_point(size=1) +
  labs(title="Quality vs. Speed")+
  theme_classic()-> plot
plot
ggplotly(plot)
```

Ahora me gustaría conectar con flechas los puntos de datos de cafa GAME.ID, ordenado por Interval. Es decir, una flecha de 0 a 1, otra de 1 a 2, y así hasta el intervalo 29 de cada juego.

He estado mirando cómo usar geom_curve o geom_segment, pero no veo que en la documentación explique cómo conectar puntos de series, o cómo definir las series para conectar varios puntos ordenados por variable.

Gracias,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tener flechas, necesitas, un orden en la dirección de las mismas y usar `geom_segment()` que permite configurar la flecha. El orden normalmente esta dado por el eje `x` en este caso `Speed` la idea final es ver como evoluciona `Quality` en función de `Speed`. ¿Podrías usar `Interval` para ordenar la dirección de las flechas? claro que sí, pero sería un gráfica más lógica si el eje `x` también fuera `INTERVAL`, sino estaríamos mostrando una dirección que no puede deducirse del propio gráfico.

Por otro lado, tiene `GAME.ID`  que funciona como grupo, por lo que podemos usar el color para diferenciar cada uno, pero antes es conveniente transformarlo en una variable categorica

```
library(tidyverse)

df_2 %>% 
  arrange(GAME.ID, Speed) %>% 
  mutate(GAME.ID = factor(GAME.ID)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Speed, y = Quality, color=GAME.ID)) + 
  geom_point(size=1) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=c(tail(Speed, n=-1), NA), yend=c(tail(Quality, n=-1), NA)),
               arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm"), type="closed")) +
  labs(title="Quality vs. Speed") +
  theme_classic()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho, no daba con ello. Me queda la duda de por qué al pasar el plot a ggplotly las flechas no se mantienen en el gráfico.

Comment: Lamentablemente parece que es un bug de plotly: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/469, fijate al final que hay un "workaround"  usando anotaciones

Comment: No pasa nada @Patricio Moracho. Gracias de todos modos. Un problema que encuentro cuando intento ordenar por INTERVAL es que me conecta el punto 29 de un GAME.ID con el punto 0 del siguiente GAME.ID. ¿Se te ocurre cómo evitar eso?

Comment: Perdona @Patricio Moracho. Me estaba uniendo los puntos porque estaba haciendo un subset de datos previo basado en otras variables. Creo que el código que das funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, el `geom_segment()` es la única gráfica que te permite poner un flecha en cada punto, pero por lo que ví, no separa los dos grupos correspondientes a cada GAME.ID, se podría eventualmente colocar dos `geom_segment()` que correspondan a cada grupo, haciendo un subset de los datos, avisame y cualquier cosa lo agrego a la respuesta.